# Is there a way to continuously get an value from a redux store one at a time? react redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

i have a async fetch that gets values like A001, A002, names and so on from an API. But sometimes i get 3 or more values with 1 api fetch and i loose some because i show only 3 values at a time in my react component.

So i look for a way to continuously show 1 entry from the store for like 2 seconds and then the next entry and so on.

Can someone please help me here?

**Actions**

```js
let lastId = 0;
let pathArray = window.location.pathname.split('/');

export const fetchLastId = () => dispatch => {
    const url = '/api/display/sites/' + pathArray[3] + '/displays/' + pathArray[5] + '/show';
    fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        mode: 'cors',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': ''
        },
        'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
    }).then(function(response) {
            return response.json();
    }).then(function(data) {
        if (data.length) {
            lastId = data[0].id;
        } else {
            lastId = 0;
        }
        console.log('Die Letzte ID war ' + lastId);
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log('Fehler: ', error);
    })
}

export const fetchLastCalls = () => dispatch => {
    const url = '/api/display/sites/' + pathArray[3] + '/displays/' + pathArray[5] + '/calls?id_greater_than=' + lastId;
    fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        mode: 'cors',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': ''
        },
        'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
    }).then(function(response) {
            return response.json();
    }).then(function(data) {
        data.reverse();
        if (data.length) {
            for (let item of data) {
                switch (item.service_id) {
                case 24:
                    dispatch({ type: 'SERVICE_1', payload: item })
                    break;
                case 25:
                    dispatch({ type: 'SERVICE_2', payload: item })
                    break;
                default:
                    console.log('Aufruf im Falschen Dienst getätigt.')
                }
                lastId = item.id;
            }
        } else {
            console.log('Keine neuen Aufrufe.');
        }    
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log('Fehler: ', error);
    })
}
```

**Reducer**

```js
let initialState = [];

function service1(state = initialState, action) {
    if (action.type === 'SERVICE_1') {
        return [action.payload, ...state];
    }
    return state;
}

export default service1;
```

**Container**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { NewCall } from '../components/NewCall';
import { LastCall } from '../components/LastCall';

import { fetchLastId , fetchLastCalls } from '../actions/index';

class Service1 extends React.Component {
    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.onFetchLastId();
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        setInterval(function() {
            this.props.onFetchLastCalls();
        }.bind(this), 1000);
    }
    renderNewTicket() {
        return this.props.calls.map(call => {
            return (
                <p key={call.ticket}>{call.ticket}</p>
            );
        });
    }
    renderNewPlace() {
        return this.props.calls.map(call => {
            return (
                <p key={call.desk_id}>{call.desk_id}</p>
            );
        });
    }
    renderLastTicket() {
        return this.props.calls.map(call => {
            return (
                <p key={call.ticket}>{call.ticket}</p>
            )
        })
    }
    renderLastPlace() {
        return this.props.calls.map(call => {
            return (
                <p key={call.desk_id}>{call.desk_id}</p>
            )
        })
    }
    componentDidUpdate() {

    }
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <NewCall 
                    call={ this.renderNewTicket() } 
                    place={ this.renderNewPlace() } 
                />
                <LastCall 
                    call={ this.renderLastTicket() } 
                    place={ this.renderLastPlace() }
                    rollOn={1} 
                />
                <LastCall 
                    call={ this.renderLastTicket() } 
                    place={ this.renderLastPlace() }
                    rollOn={2} 
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        calls: state.service1
    };
}

let mapDispatchToProps = {
  onFetchLastId: fetchLastId,
  onFetchLastCalls: fetchLastCalls
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Service1);
```

**1 Output Component**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Textfit } from 'react-textfit';

import Blink from './Blink';

const inlineStyle = {
    width: 945,
    height: 249
};

export class NewCall extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <div className="flex-item-grey ticketNrGr">
                    <Textfit mode="multi" style={inlineStyle} className="textfit" max={200}><Blink>{this.props.call[0]}</Blink></Textfit>
                </div>
                <div className="flex-item-grey platzNrGr">
                    <Textfit mode="multi" style={inlineStyle} className="textfit" max={200}><Blink>{this.props.place[0]}</Blink></Textfit>        
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**Second Output Component**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Textfit } from 'react-textfit';

const inlineStyleCall = {
    width: 735,
    height: 195
};

const inlineStyleDesk = {
    width: 200,
    height: 195
};

export class LastCall extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div className="flex-container-aufrufKl">
                <div className="flex-item-grey ticketNrKl">
                    <Textfit mode="multi" style={inlineStyleCall} className="textfit" max={200}>{this.props.call[this.props.rollOn]}</Textfit>
                </div>
                <div className="flex-item-grey platzNrKl">
                    <Textfit mode="multi" style={inlineStyleDesk} className="textfit" max={200}>{this.props.place[this.props.rollOn]}</Textfit>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: show some code so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like it should be the responsibility of the component to trigger a new action to render the next available value. So you could have a component that accepts the value `value` and a boolean indicating if there are any more values: `hasMoreValues`.

In your react component, you'll need to make it a class to access the lifecycle hooks and hook into the `componentDidMount` function:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        if(this.props.hasMoreValues) {
           setTimeout(this.props.showNextValue, 2000)
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>{this.props.value}</div>
        )
    }
}

export default connect(
    (props) => ({
        hasMoreValues: getHasMoreValues(),
        value: getNextValue(),
    )},
    {
        showNextValue: () => { type: 'SHOW_NEXT_ACTION' },
    },
)
```

An approach like this means that the trigger is still coming from the application. The next thing to do is update the item to view to be the next one available in your reducer, but I'll leave that up to you.